# Extract lone upper case letters from a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract all "lone" capital letters from a string.
By "lone" I mean - not followed or preceded by alphanumeric charachter, punctuation symbols, brackets and such..

So for this input:

> this L iS A String 'A' -T- xxAxx women's (M)

I want this output:

```
['L', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'M']
```

I tried:

`re.findall(r'[A-Z]',"this L iS A String 'A' -T- xxAxx women's (M)")`

but it results in :

```
['L', 'S', 'A', 'S', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'M']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries `\b[A-Z]\b` to match only lone upper case letters.

Python code,

```
import re

print(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\b',"this L iS A String 'A' -T- xxAxx women's (M)"))
```

Prints your expected output,

```
['L', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'M']
```

In case you want it to match one or more upper case letters, use `\b[A-Z]+\b`